# How to fix Nameservers list [ns1.myserver.com., ns2.myserver.com.] different from NS Records: []

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record

In Windows Server I have a DNS Server where I add NS records ns1.myserver.com and ns2.myserver.com. On domain panel I set the nameservers to point to the ns1.myserver.com and ns2.myserver.com.

This work for all my domains but not for .it domains. When I test the domain from dns-check.nic.it it fail with the error: `Nameservers list [ns1.myserver.com., ns2.myserver.com.] different from NS Records: []`

What I have to configure in my dns server to pass this test?

Comment: Downvote a question without comment don't help to improve it

Comment: not having any issues with the dns records at myserver.com, maybe post real data, details, etc.

Comment: @JacobEvans Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I can't post real domain for customer privacy. Also I was not able to post more details before to figure out the meaning of this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem.

In DNS Server is necessary to add NS records in each domains not only for the domain used in the domain register panel.

In my case I have for example myserver.com and another domain mysite.it

The NS records configured in domain register panel for the domain mysite.it are ns1.myserver.com, ns2.myserver.com

In DNS Server I added NS records ns1.myserver.com, ns2.myserver.com for the domain myserver.com but I have not added the same NS records for the domain mysite.it

When I added the NS records ns1.myserver.com, ns2.myserver.com also in the domain mysite.it all works fine.